# VSCode unable to install Jupyter / Python Extension

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter

I had to set up my Computer again and tried to install the Python Extension in VSCode. 
When I try to install this extension I get the following error:

> Unable to install extension 'ms-toolsai.jupyter' as it is not compatible with VS Code '1.54.1'.

To install the Python Extension, Jupyter is needed but this Extension seems to be broken in the newest VSCode version.
Anyone run into the same error and knows a fix for this without downgrading VSCode?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Windows with WSL

Comment: What extension are you trying to get - what is the name?

Comment: Python 
ms-python.python 
v2021.2.633441544

Comment: @Robert Fent -It is recommended that you find the VS Code extension folders "_ms-python.python-2021.2_" and "_ms-toolsai.jupyter-2021.3_" in "_C:\Users\username\.vscode\extensions_" and remove or delete these two files Folder, then reopen VS Code and reinstall these two extensions.

Comment: @JillCheng unfortunatly this is not working. Still getting the same error after reinstalling the removed extensions

Comment: @Robert Fent -This is strange, please try to re-download the [VS Code installation package](https://code.visualstudio.com/Download) and reinstall it and the required extensions.

Comment: @JillCheng Had to reinstall complete VSCode but still got same error. downloading .visx and installing it manually fixed it

Comment: I am not on Windows and I am having the same issue with vscode 1.58.0. I still can't load the vsix manually, same error! Anyone having this issue?

Comment: Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67205667/installation-of-jupyter-failed/70198483

Answer (score 1):

OS: Manjaro KDE

I tried installing code and upgrading to insiders (AUR) using pacman and did not get Python to install in vscode because of the Jupyter error. I tried installing Jupyter vsix manually and this also failed.

I ended up getting Python in to vscode by installing code using snap. https://snapcraft.io/code

Answer (score 0):

If python/other extension on VS Code is unable to be installed, then:

1. You should uninstall VS code first, then clear the temp and prefetch file.
2. After that, go to `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming` and delete Code folder there.
3. Now Restart your PC and install VS Code Again.

Thats It. Done.