# Installation of Jupyter failed

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter, offline

OS : RHEL8

LAN : Offline

VS Code Ver. : 1.55.2

jupyter : ms-toolsai.jupyter-2021.6.770905982.vsix

"Unable to install extension 'ms-toolsai.jupyter' as it is not compatible with VS Code '1.55.2'."

I tried a different version of VSCode and Jupyter combination, but it was not successful.

Comment: How did you install the "Jupyter" extension in VS Code? Have you tried reinstalling VS Code?

Comment: I solved it.
I downloaded and installed Insiders of VSCode, and Jupyter was installed normally.

Comment: I tried this and failed using vscode v1.58. OS is Manjaro KDE, installed vscode (official repository) and upgraded it to installers (https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/code-features-insiders). I also tried installing it from file (*.vsix) (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-toolsai.jupyter) but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 3):

1. Download extension
2. Unzip it as zip
3. In extensions/package.json change "engines"."vscode" to compatible vscode version
4. Zip extension folder
5. Change zipped extension name from "extension.zip" to "extension.vsix"
6. Install "extension.vsix" to vscode via "Install from VSIX..."

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, please refer to the following:

1. Please use the latest version of VS Code and the "Jupyter" extension to avoid version incompatibility.
2. Please try to find the location of the extension installed by VS Code, then try to remove or delete the folder of the "Jupyter" extension, then reopen VS Code and reinstall the "Jupyter" extension. (`\Users\username\.vscode\extensions`)

   [image]
3. If it still doesn't work, please reinstall [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/Download).

Reference: [Jupyter in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support).

Comment: I tried everything you suggested.
But it all failed.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can only install stable versions of Jupyter-VSIX (even build numbers) on VS Code if not using insiders version.
2. The releases of Jupyter-VSIX is lock-stepped with the releases of VS Code so you must use the correct stable version of Jupyter-VSIX on your VS Code setup.

Unfortunately, the VSIX files doesn't contain release/change information about what version of VS Code they are locked to that I could find :/

Answer (score 0):

Update: I was experiencing this issue due to a proxy server interfering with the installation. The resolution I provided below allowed me to get the update installed without having to deal with the proxy server. I could have also worked with our network team to request a bypass of the proxy server for the site the extension was being installed from.

Resolution that worked for me:

1. Search for the Jupyter extension in VS Code and click install.
2. When the install fails, download and save off the VSIX file for the
   current Jupyter extension version from VS Code.
3. Save the file off on the desktop or some accessible location.
4. IMPORTANT: Remove the PC's connection to the internet by unplugging the
   ethernet cable from the desktop, disconnecting from wifi, etc.
5. Select the option from VS Code to manually install the file.
6. Browse to the downloaded VSIX file and select it for install.
7. The file should then successfully install.

Detailed explanation:
I was running into similar error messages as reported here, at times getting simply the error "XHR failed: Download: XHR failed" and at other times the error "Unable to install extension 'ms-toolsai.jupyter' as it is not compatible with VS Code ''". In my case, the versions I was attempting with were VS Code 1.68.0 - 1.69.2 and Jupyter extensions ranging from v2022.5.x - 2022.6.x. I was also attempting to download inside a corporate network, which likely meant I was dealing with proxy issues and thus also likely why, when I disconnected the PC and took it offline, it finally then allowed me to install the extension.

I tried a lot of other suggestions I could find out there like the following, but none of these suggestions worked for me.

1. Turning the http: proxy support off in VS Code
2. Deleting the "http.proxyAuthorization": null code along with its
   brackets in the settings.json VS Code file
3. Unzipping the VSIX install file and modifying the InstallationTarget Version in the extension.vsixmanifest file,

A few helpful notes I discovered along the way:

If you want to download a specific version of the Jupyter extension, you can navigate to the following marketplace link, changing out the version listed in the URL with the version you need. You'll need to know the specific version number for this to work:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/_apis/public/gallery/publishers/ms-toolsai/vsextensions/jupyter/2022.6.1001902341/vspackage

GitHub discussions site on Jupyter:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/discussions

Jupyter marketplace site:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-toolsai.jupyter&ssr=false#overview